# How to resolve error: this.contentWindow.Drupal is undefined, while uploading images using media module?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, media

I have updated

`drupal core` version from `7.50 to 7.59` and updated

`media module` to `7.x.2.19`.

After that I got **error:** `this.contentWindow.Drupal is undefined in the console`

[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: I have media 7.x-3.0-rc5 version. And 7.59 drupal core. I don't have any error message, why you don't update to media 7.x-2.19, which is remcomended  by project's maintainer.

Comment: i have update 7.x-2.19 media module however i am getting same error.

Comment: Ok. Check a couple things, did you also update the file entity module?. If you didn't, do it, update to the 7.x-2.22 version. If it doesn't work either, please change your Jquery update version and see if that works.

Comment: File entity module is 7.x-2.22 and jquery update module 7.x-2.7 is already updated.

Comment: I mean this jquery version that you configure here: /admin/config/development/jquery_update

Comment: I've been searching about your issue in google. And there are a lot of issues with media.popup.js file, but all of them (at least what I saw) belong to the 2.x version. So I  recomend you to update to 3.x version: https://www.drupal.org/project/media/releases/7.x-3.x-dev

Comment: Thanks Daniela i will try that thank you for your support.

Comment: HI @Daniela this issue is related to cloud flare . i include cloudflare rocket.js, which cause this issue.

Comment: Did you fix it?

Comment: yes this issue is resolved after removing cloudflare rocket.js, there is no issue in the media module or other js. cloudflare rocket.js conflict other js of media module. t

Comment: Great! thanks to let me know.